# producing a GET response to an ajax POST

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

In javascript I am POSTing with ajax and I need to get a reply from my Python program. The following code shows the javascript, but how does I produce the desired `responseText` from a GET on the Python side?
In this example I am want a Yes or No reply to a question for the user as to whether to change the name provided or not.

I understand how to receive the name and value in the python POST, but I don't know how to produce the response in the associated python GET.

```
function changeName(name,value){
    var json = '[{';
    json += '"name":"'+name+'",'
    json += '"value":"'+value+'"}]'
    loadDoc(json,"edit")
}

function loadDoc(data,url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", ("/"+url), true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text");  #or something
  xhttp.send(data);
}
```

My typical response in Python GETs follows one of the following 2 patterns, but neither seems to allow me to reply in this case.

```
self.response.out.write(template.render( template_values))
return webapp2.redirect("/templatename/%s" % variable)
```

(No PHP or jquery, please.)

Comment: You may follow this to understand how you may provide a service endpoint for GET in Python: https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

Comment: Am I correct that there is no way to directly read either `template_values` or the `variable` with `self.responseText`? Is the only alternative to place the needed result into the datastore in python and then read that result in javascript when the callback function is ready? I am using google-app-engine, so that is the datastore to which I refer.

Comment: I suspect the right approach is to use something like the following where I am trying to return an integer value. Can someone improve on this, because it's not quite working for me. And I don't know how to parse the result in this.responseText either. `self.response.out.write("\t".join( str(party.rounds)))` `self.response.out.write("\n")`

Comment: For example, when I respond as follows, the result of `this.responseText` is `undefined`, not `text`. `self.response.out.write("text")`

Comment: Surely, there is a way to do this. [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp) gives examples with php and .asp , but does not show the php or .asp, for example. [At the following link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp) a Post example is shown, too.  Please point me to an example using Post and self.responseText with python.

Comment: Duh! I was not responding from the GET, but from the POST. `self.response.out.write("text")` works perfectly from the GET.